# How to do EF migration by Azure Dev Ops release pipeline to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-devops, entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a setup where all components are in Azure cloud and I want to do **entity framework migration** against an Azure SQL database in the Azure Devops release pipeline.

When running the release pipeline in Azure Devops, the release pipeline is run under a **service principle** that I have to grant access to the database with elevated privilegies.

The migration works with username and password but that is not secure and I don´t want to use it.

How do I do that ?
And is this the correct way to authenticate the connection between Azure Devops and the database ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the **EF Core Migration Bundles** introduced [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-devops-friendly-ef-core-migration-bundles/) in your Azure Pipelines to do the EF migration.

Try to run the following steps in your pipeline:

1. Run the following commands to install the bundles.

   ```bash
   dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version xxxx
   ```

   Or update the bundles.

   ```bash
   dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version xxxx
   ```
2. Run the following commands to generate the bundle in the working directory of your project that contains the EF Core migrations.

   ```bash
   dotnet ef migrations bundle
   ```
3. Run the following commands to deploy your migrations.

   ```bash
   ./bundle --connection {connection strin}
   ```

More related articles:

- [**Applying Migrations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)
- [**Run EF Core Migrations in Azure DevOps**](https://dotnetthoughts.net/run-ef-core-migrations-in-azure-devops/)

---